# Extracting "tag1, tag2" values from a column in LibreOffice-calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I've got a LibreOffice calc spreadsheet with columns containing some freeform text, followed by a column with "tags" which I've entered (coded interview data). For example:

```
1234,"some explanation goes here","tag1, tag2, tag3"
5678,"a different one here","tag1, tag4"
```

What's the easiest way of creating a sheet with a row for each tag, and a column for each "row index" or whatever e.g.

```
tag1,1234,5678
tag2,1234
tag3,1234
tag4,5678
```

I know a spreadsheet isn't the ideal tool for this by the way, but I'm on the clock and don't have time to learn a complex package. I could process it in python, but I'm wary of getting sidetracked!